# Vectorize greedy assignment in numpy

Tags: numpy, vectorization

The algorithm below extracts a one-to-one relation from a many-to-many relation in a greedy fashion, progressively excluding used-up items. Is there a way to vectorize this algorithm with numpy?

```py
# The relation [(x0, y0), (x1, y1), ...] is parametrized as
# left_items = [x0, x1, ...]
# right_items = [y0, y1, ...]
def compute_greedy_assignment(
    left_items: List[int], 
    right_items: List[int],
) -> Tuple[List[int], List[int]]:
    left_selected = []
    right_selected = []
    for left, right in zip(left_items, right_items):
        if not left in left_selected and not right in right_selected:
            left_selected.append(left)
            right_selected.append(right)
    return left_selected, right_selected
```

Comment: `np.unique` with argument `return_index=True` may help